# Why are my errors so high for my minimized solution?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, statsmodels, scipy-optimize

I have a couple of large datasets that I am attempting to generate a theoretical model of. I am able to find a global minima/solution for this fitting, but when I attempt to calculate errors, they come out to be large even though the landscape is well defined.

I have the adjustable parameter of the solution I'm trying to get, and 3 adjustable parameters to modify my "model" so it can match my experimental (these are just scaling factors, a single constant applied to the entire model).

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import minimize

def fun(k,io,exp_data,exp_error,model1,model2):
    F=(np.sqrt((8*k[0]*io)+k[0]**2)-k[0])/4
    C=(-np.sqrt(k[0])*np.sqrt((8*io)+k[0])+k[0]+(4*io))/4
    fraction_F=np.tile(((np.array([F/io],dtype=float)).reshape((len(model1),1))),(len(model1[0]))) # this is a single value, but I need it to be applied to all datasets since the datasets are list of lists
    fraction_C=np.tile(((np.array([C/io],dtype=float)).reshape((len(model1),2))),(len(model2[0])))
    comb_model=(F*model1)+(C/2*model2)
    resize_scaling_factor=np.tile(((np.array(k[1:])).reshape((len(comb_model),1))),(len(comb_model[0]))) #same as before a constant to be applied to the datasets
    return ((np.sum(((exp_data-(resize_scaling_factor*comb_model))/exp_error)**2))/comb_model.size) #normalized chi2

minimize(fun,args=(io,exp_data,exp_error,model1,model2),bounds=((0,np.inf),)*4,method='Nelder-Mead',x0=[1000]+[1e-9]*3)
```

The solution for k, which is what I care about, is around 500-1000, and the scaling factors are all very small (1e-8 to 1e-11). This setup, I can find the solution quite nicely. If I look at the  chi2 landscape
[image]

We can see a nice minima can be found around ~400ish. I would assume then the errors for this solution should be small as well. However when I calculate the errors:

```
from numpy.linalg import inv
from statsmodels.tools import approx_hess2
solution=minimize(fun,args=(io,exp_data,exp_error,model1,model2),bounds=((0,np.inf),)*4,method='Nelder-Mead',x0=[1000]+[1e-9]*3)
error=np.sqrt(np.diag(inv(approx_hess2(solution.x,fun,args=(io,exp_data,exp_error,model1,model2)))))
```

The errors are larger than the solution

```
428+/-593 #first value is solution from minimization, 2nd value is the inverse Hessian diagonal
#albeit errors for scaling factors are better
7.91e-10+/-4.5e-11
1.72e-9+/-5.34e-11
3.52e-9+/-6.3e-11 
#we can see all scaling factors have small errors relative to solution, so why is this not true of the other solution considering the well defined landscape
```

From my understanding, everything is setup correctly, my chi2 for my data is good (it's normalized to error, so it should be close to 1 which it is). The scaling factors have small errors. So I don't know why my other solution has such high errors (based off the graph it should not be +/-500, maybe like +/- 50 or something).

Any help would greatly be appreciated!

Comment: `However when I calculate the errors:` I'm not following what you're doing in this step. Are you evaluating your loss function, and finding that it's larger than you expect? Are you calculating the minimum in two different ways and finding that they differ? What does 'error' mean in this context?

Comment: @NickODell I'm calculating the Hessian, then looking at the diagonal of the inverse of said Hessian (i.e. the variances in you covariance matrix). The variance for the scaling factors are fine, but the variance for the first value is large and I don't understand why despite a good convex landscape for the variable.

I combined a bunch in one step but approx_hess2 calculates the Hessian. Inv takes the inverse (covariance matrix), and I want  the diagonal of that inverse (which would be the variances in the covariance matrix). I take the square root of the diagonal values to get errors

Comment: Can you show the values for arguments you're sending to your objective via `minimize`?

Comment: @Reinderien The arguments are large arrays i.e. exp_data and exp_error are 3x500 matrices. Model1 and Model2 are 1x5000 arrays (I modify them to match exp_data in the rest of my script). I could post them if you'd like, but it'd make everything very ugly

Comment: @samman Are the exact values important to the question, or could you replace them with `np.random.randn()`, and still display the same behavior?

Comment: @NickODell The exact values are unfortunately important. I didn't quite know how to ask the question without posting them, but because they are large datasets I also didn't know how to post them without this just being a large sheet of values. Since ultimately my question is, why does my minimized solution have such large errors. Random values would result in random solutions and random errors. I was hoping maybe I could get a more conceptual answer, maybe I set something up incorrectly or misunderstood something in calculating errors?

Comment: Or maybe just having a the above landscape I show doesn't imply you should have low errors. If you know where I could post large datasets, I could post them there.

Comment: @samman I'm not super familiar with the math here, but I'm not sure the inverse Hessian can really be thought of as "error." The minimize solution is exact within a configurable tolerance, assuming that the function is convex. It seems like what you're measuring is that the first parameter is way more important than the other parameters.

Comment: @NickODell From my understanding the inverse Hessian is the covariance matrix. Subsequently, the diagonal of the covariance matrix is the variances (i.e. the uncertainties or errors of your solutions). With the off-diagonals of the inverse Hessian being the covariances of the solutions

Comment: @samman If I apply that method to the function `0.01*(x**2 + y**2)`, I get a variance of 7, even though the solution is within 1E-8 of the right answer. [notebook link](https://gist.github.com/nickodell/055ebcd11a86de4a9efcfd2ff5bbe57d)

Comment: @NickODell that is correct. That's why I know the setup is working properly because you can see in your notebook you got the same answer in the Inv Hessian from BGFS as well (~7). My question is why is it so large though?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253787/discussion-between-samman-and-nick-odell).